# Run Non-Visual GUI App from LocalSystem Service

Tags: delphi, user-interface, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2, external-process

### Background

We need to run a GUI application from a Windows Service, set to Log On as **Local System** (and without enabling *interact with desktop*).

The GUI application takes one command-line parameter, performs a specific task and then self-terminates.  It is a GUI app because some of its components require a parent `TForm`, so a console app doesn't work.  There are no dialogs or any UI a user would see.  In fact, it creates itself as a hidden form with no taskbar icon:

```
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False; // <- No taskbar icon
  Application.ShowMainForm := False;      // <- Main form is hidden
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
```

It is possible that the GUI app may be launched multiple times simultaneously, each with its own command-line parameter.  Since a GUI app can't be spawned directly in the **Session 0** process of the service, I created an *Administrator* user account so the service can log on the admin user and run the GUI app as the admin user.  Once I get it to work once, I will leave this user logged in so the service can quickly launch the GUI app without the login/logout overhead each time it spawns the GUI app.

### What I've Done

I'm using the following code, formed from dozens of discussions on this topic, even though most of them wanted the GUI app to be seen by a logged on user.

```
function CreateEnvironmentBlock(var lpEnvironment: Pointer; hToken: THandle; bInherit: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external 'userenv.dll';
function DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; external 'userenv.dll';

var
  _usertoken: THandle;
  _si: _STARTUPINFOW;
  _pi: _PROCESS_INFORMATION;
  _env: Pointer;
  _sid: Cardinal;
begin
  if LogonUser(PChar(Username), PChar('localhost'), PChar(Password), LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, _usertoken) then
    try
      ZeroMemory(@_si, SizeOf(_si));
      _si.cb := SizeOf(_si);
//    _si.lpDesktop := 'WinSta0\Default'; // <- behaves the same with or without this

      if CreateEnvironmentBlock(_env, _usertoken, False) then
        try
          if CreateProcessAsUser(_usertoken, nil, PChar(sCMD), nil, nil, False, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, _env, nil, _si, _pi) then
          begin
            WaitForSingleObject(_pi.hProcess, 30000);
            CloseHandle(_pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(_pi.hProcess);
          end
          else
            _handle_error('CreateProcessAsUser() failed.');
        finally
          DestroyEnvironmentBlock(_env);
        end
      else
        _handle_error('CreateEnvironmentBlock() failed.');
    finally
      CloseHandle(_usertoken);
    end
  else
    _handle_error('LogonUser() failed.');
end;
```

The Windows Event Viewer [Security Log] shows an entry when `LogonUser()` is called.  The following *privileges* appear in the log entry:

```
  SeTcbPrivilege
  SeSecurityPrivilege
  SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
  SeLoadDriverPrivilege
  SeBackupPrivilege
  SeRestorePrivilege
  SeDebugPrivilege
  SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
  SeImpersonatePrivilege
```

`sCmd` is set to *"c:\path\myapp.exe" "parameter"*.  When `sCmd` was **not** properly set, `CreateProcessAsUser()` would fail with an error of *2 - The system cannot find the file specified.*  Once I fixed that, `CreateProcessAsUser()` returns `True`, but it never actually launches the GUI application.

### Question

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I would appreciate any help with getting the service to launch the GUI app under the logged on Username/Password profile, if that's the right way to do this.  Or, if there is a better way to do it, I would appreciate any direction and insight.

Comment: Don't try to run GUI apps from services.

Comment: In addition to what David said, I'd also question that components require a TForm owner. If they're non-GUI, you should be able to pass Nil into the Constructor and if they're GUI, they shouldn't be in the app in the first place.

Comment: You really are looking at this all the wrong way. If you've written code that requires `TForm` owners for non-visual code, then you simply need to fix that. Remove that needless restriction.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I agree it is not a good idea.  But the process needs to run server-side.  We tried building it as a Console App, but one of the 3rd party components returns an error `Control has no parent window.`  I would love to run it as a console app, but it needs to be a GUI app because of the *no parent window* issue.

Comment: Some things are impossible. Have you contemplated the fact that you might not be able to create GUI in session 0? Why are you trying to put GUI into session 0 anyway? And why are you disabling "Allow service to interact with desktop" when that's what you are trying to do? What is this visual component that you want to put in a service?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the component we use to render our database content it `TRichViewEdit`, which uses Windows API calls that require a parent window.  I don't want to put this into the service itself.  Thus the need to spawn an external app, albeit a GUI app.  I am okay with allowing the service to interact with the desktop if needed.

Comment: It's not so much that it runs in the service, that it runs in session 0. You might need to run the code in the service and allow it to interact with the desktop. Or you might need to run the separate process on an interactive desktop. Ideally you want rendering that doesn't require visual components but I do see that's not easy for you to get starting where you are.

Comment: I like the idea of running in a separate process on the interactive desktop.  With all I've read, I think the code in the question is pretty close to what I need.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is the best post of the subject that I know of: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx

Comment: @JamesL.: why are you using a visual control (and a user input field at that) to create non-visual database content?  In any case, you don't need a `TForm` parent, you could use `CreateWindow/Ex()` to create a hidden window and assign it to the control's `ParentWindow` property, or pass it to the control's `CreateParented()` constructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - `TRichViewEdit` was used to generate a bunch of user-contributed content.  We need to re-render the content now as part of a separate process, and the only way to properly render the original content is to use the original control (`TRichViewEdit`).  I like your suggestion about using `CreateWindow/Ex()`.  I'll give that a try today.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I'm hopeful that Remy's suggestion will make it possible to run the external process as a console app.  If not, I'll be taking a very close look at the article you provided.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to David, Remy and Andy for comments.  It helped me to step back and look at the issues from a fresh point-of-view.  *The solutions ended up being very simple.*

### Problem 1 - GUI Apps and "Session 0" Services Processes

A service cannot have UI elements or spawn a program that has UI elements.  I thought this meant I couldn't use any GUI type controls, like `TForm` or `TWinControl` components.  So I was trying to figure out how to launch a GUI program from a service (e.g., to the interactive desktop or by logging a user on and launching it to their desktop).

Turns out that as long as you don't have a dialog or some visual control that a user needs to interact with or respond to, it works perfectly fine to include GUI components in a service or an app the service spawns.

### Problem 2 - "Control has no parent window"

I found one instance in my code where I created a control at runtime and didn't set its parent.  Hard to track down, but fixed.

### Problem 3 - External App only launched under "my" user profile

I set the service to `Log On` three ways, 1) as **Local System**, 2) as my username/password, and 3) as another admin user's username/password (with identical rights as me).

In all three instances, the return code from within the service to launch the external app indicated it successfully launched the app.  However, only when the service was set to `Log On` using my username/password would the app actually run.

I found a information message in the *system* event log that said a BPL wasn't found for both of the other two instances.  This was because I have a personal user path environment variable that includes an entry for the BPL directory.  The other admin user and the **Local System** accounts do not have this.  So of course the app failed to load the needed BPLs and therefore could not run.

### Problem 4 - LocalSystem Access to File System

When we pushed the new code and modules to our production servers, the external app failed to properly launch and perform its task (but this time with no messages in the Windows event logs).

There are several parameters that the external app needs (too many to pass on the command line) so the service places all of the parameters into a uniquely named INI file and pass the name of the INI file to the external app.  Once the external app finishes its task, it deletes the INI file.

As it turns out, the external app was launched using the **Local System** account, which didn't have access to the file system and therefore could not open/use the INI file.  Once we granted the appropriate rights to the **Local System** account, it started working correctly in our production environment as well.

Everything works great now.